# Extend the time duration in my jquery popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jquery pop up plugin, when i submit the form it will close automatically. but i need to set time limit for the pop up window.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class='popbox'>
<a class='open' href='#'>
  <img src='plus.png' style='width:14px;position:relative;'> Click Here!
</a>

<div class='collapse'>
  <div class='box'>
    <div class='arrow'></div>
    <div class='arrow-border'></div>

    <form action="" method="post" id="subForm">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="cm-name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="cm-nklki-nklki" id="nklki-nklki" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <textarea name="cm-f-tlhll" id="Message" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Get In Touch" /> <a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>
      <input type="button" name="closebutton" id="closebutton" value="closebutton" >
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 (function () {
   $.fn.popbox = function (options) {
     var settings = $.extend({
       selector: this.selector,
       open: '.open',
       box: '.box',
       arrow: '.arrow',
       arrow_border: '.arrow-border',
       close: '.close'
     }, options);
     var methods = {
       open: function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var pop = $(this);
         var box = $(this).parent().find(settings['box']);
         if (box.css('display') == 'block') {
           methods.delay(1500).close();
         } else {
           box.css({
             'display': 'block',
             'top': 10,
             'left': ((pop.parent().width() / 2) - box.width() / 2)
           });
         }
       },
       close: function () {
         $(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");
       }
     };
     $(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 27) {
         methods.delay(1500).close();
       }
     });
     return this.each(function () {
       //$(this).css({'width': $(settings['box']).width()}); // Width needs to be set otherwise popbox will not move when window resized.
       $(settings['open'], this).bind('click', methods.open);
       $(settings['open'], this).parent().find(settings['close']).bind('click', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         methods.close();
       });
     });
   }
 }).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the `delay(1500)` to a higher value. 1500 is in milliseconds, which means your current popup will close in 1.5 seconds.

Comment: The time out is worked on when i close the button, but it fails in form submission. for ex when i hit the submit button it close immediately. but i need to increase the close time.

Comment: Replace 
'$(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");' 
with 
'$(settings['box']).fadeOut(1500);'

Answer (score 0):

```
close: function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");
    }, 1000); // 1 second
}
```

Comment: @Koenyn it is better to explain your solution rather than just posting code.

Comment: ok, so basically, you need to "delay" the action after they click close right? so instead I'm adding a timeout inside the close function. which will only fire the fadeout 1 second after they click close. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: If you want the fadeout to be slower you should add a time into that i.e. $(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast", 1500); http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/